# Knockout JS Remove not working

Tags: knockout.js

I have some very basic binding .. working.
Now I am trying to delete a row. It is not working.

http://jsfiddle.net/uC8Vt/57/

I am not passing the correct

```
var ClientModel = function () {

    this.clients = ko.observableArray(data); // Load json data

    self.del = function(elem) { 
        if (confirm('Delete:  ' + elem.Name)) {
            this.client.remove(elem);
        };
    }
}
```

I am not sure why the remove is not working.

Comment: There's a typo on this line, for a start.
    `this.client.remove(elem);`
Should be `clients`.

That doesn't resolve the issue though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functions for selection and deletion are in the parent view model, so you should call them with `$parent.select` and `$parent.del`.

Also this line had some mistakes:

```
self.clients.remove(elem);
```

Here is the [fixed jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pomber/uC8Vt/60/).

Comment: To expand on this answer (which is a bit confusing as the linked jsfiddle fixes the problem differently to the answer), the `this` variable on this line `this.clients.remove(elem);` refers to the `elem` object, due to the current scope. You can either refer to the parent element, as this answer mentions, or you can use `self`, as this refers to the parent element in the scope of the delete function (due to the line `var self = this;` being called outside of the delete function).

Comment: Sorry, I added one more line that I didn't mention `var self = this;`

Answer (score 0):

For one thing - change  this.client.remove(elem);
to:
 self.clients.remove(elem);

You specified "this" instead of "self", and "client" instead of "clients"